# nginx; return response code if a file exists by using try_files only

Tags: nginx

Since [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) I've been trying to set up a configuration using the directive `try_files` only so that a maintenance page is displayed together with the response code 503, for any URI without exception, i.e. including php pages, if a maintenance file exist.

There are two problems with my configuration:

1. The maintenance page does not display for php URIs.
2. The response code 503 is not returned if the maintenance.html file exists.

I've seen similar questions [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5600448/1257965),[[2]](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,226232) but none with a solution that uses `try_files` only (as opposed the using the `if` directive) and that unconditionally serves a maintenance page with the response code 503, if the corresponding file is present. Is such a solution possible?

Below is my current non-working conf file. It doesn't contain a 503 response code setting because I don't understand where it's supposed to go in order for it to work as described above.

```
worker_processes            1;

error_log                   /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

events {
    worker_connections      1024;
}

http {
    include                 mime.types;
    default_type            application/octet-stream;

    index                   index.php index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen                  80;
        server_name             rpi;
        root                    /www;

        location / {
            try_files           /maintenance.html $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

            # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
            location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files           $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass        unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index       index.php;
                include             fastcgi.conf;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess that my question could alternatively be phrased like this: Can `try_files` be made to work as an `if` control structure? If not by itself, can it, with the above goal, be combined with other directives to act as such, excluding the `if` directive?

**edit:** Below is a solution using `if` that I'm currently using by including it in the server section:

```
error_page              503 @maintenance;

if (-f $document_root/maintenance.html) {
        return          503;
}

location @maintenance {
        try_files       /maintenance.html =404;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Very good question! But it's not possible at all unless you call some kind of script that sets the correct response code.

### A working solution only with nginx and no if

The [`try_files` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) is only performing an internal redirect for the last statement. But we can combine it with the [`index` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) and force an internal redirect.

```
# This will be the HTML file to display for the 503 error.
error_page 503 /maintenance/maintenance.html;

# Let nginx know that this particular file is only for internal redirects.
location = /maintenance/maintenance.html {
  internal;
}

# Any request that starts with the maintenance folder is 503!
location ^~ /maintenance/ {
  return 503;
}

# Instead of checking if a file exists and directly delivering it we check
# if a certain directory exists and trigger our index directive which will
# perform an internal redirect for us.
location / {
  expires epoch;
  try_files /maintenance/ $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

#### Any drawbacks with this method?

- Actual 301 redirect to the directory instead of staying at the same URL (search engines).
- Browser caching of 301 redirects might be an issue, that's why I added the `expires epoch` to the location block.

### Other solutions?

#### Via nginx configuration file

Instead of creating an HTML file, why not create an nginx configuration file and simply reload the process?

- Much better performance!
- Easier to understand!
- No side effects!

The nginx configuration could look like the following (note that this `if` isn't evil at all):

```
error_page 503 /maintenance.html;

location / {
  include maintenance.conf;
  if ($maintenance = 1) {
    return 503;
  }
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Content of the `maintenance.conf` file:

```
set $maintenance 0;
```

And if you want to activate the maintenance mode (in your shell):

```
echo set $maintenance 1;> maintenance.conf && service nginx reload
```

**More advanced for shell friends**
You could even extend an init script with this, for instance [my LSB compliant one](https://github.com/Fleshgrinder/nginx-sysvinit-script) by replacing the following block at the end of the file:

```
*)
  echo "Usage: ${NAME} {force-reload|reload|restart|start|status|stop}" >&2
  exit 1
;;
```

With the following block:

```
maintenance)
  echo "set $maintenance 1;" > /etc/nginx/maintenance.conf && service nginx reload;
;;

production)
  echo "set $maintenance 0;" > /etc/nginx/maintenance.conf && service nginx reload;
;;

*)
  echo "Usage: ${NAME} {force-reload|reload|restart|start|status|stop|maintenance|production}" >&2
  exit 1
;;
```

And now you can simply execute the following command (including auto-completion) to go into maintenance mode:

```
service nginx maintenance
```

Or the following to go back into production:

```
service nginx production
```

#### With a script / PHP file

Another extremely easy approach that would work like a charm is to use a PHP file that handles it.

```
location / {
    try_files /maintenance.php $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Your PHP file would look exactly like your HTML file, you only have to add the following to it's beginning (assuming PHP 5.4+):

```
<?php http_response_code(503) ?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- ... more html ... -->
```